# use private variable in controller with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, oop, object, view

```
private $cart;

public function __construct() {
    $this->cart = DB::table('carts')->get();
}

public function index(){
    return view('carts.index')->with(compact('$this->cart));
}
```

I'm using Laravel and I want to give a private variable in view, is it possible ?
Thanks in advance ! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can just not use `compact` and create the array yourself:

```
...->with(['cart' => $this->cart]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass that variable in the function, no need to declare it as a private.

```
public function index(){
    return view('carts.index')->with(['cart' => DB::table('carts')->get()]);
}
```